# convert csv file into xlsx using apache poi and java

Tags: java, apache-poi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrVYY.png)I have a csv file which contains some extra data at starting and empty rows in between before start actual table.

It gives me error while mapping .file is not readable in APACHE poi.

So what to do now?

```
    String SAMPLECSVFILEPATH = "pathtocsvfile";
    XSSFWorkbook wb=null;
    XSSFSheet sheet=null;
    Reader reader = 
             Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLECSVFILEPATH));
    CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
    List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
    System.out.println(csvRecords);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/home/yuktamedia/Downloads/HP/report1.xlsx");
    for(CSVRecord str: csvRecords){
        writer.write(str);
    }
    writer.close();
```

This code generates file but not in form of row column wise
http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2012/12/Convert-CSV-Excel-2007-Java-Example-Program-POI.html i reffered this one also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwRo8.png)

so it gives me file like this

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide: sample of input file, the exact error you have, what you expect to get and the actual sample of file you currently generate

Comment: You are not using any of the XSSF* classes to write your data. You only read the CSV correctly. You still need to create the row and the cell with the data.

Comment: i want excel file . but my file contains initial row with  description data so when i mapping this file takes that as header but my tabledata starts from line no 15.

Comment: i also done this by using xssf and creating line and cell but the problem is when i m reading next line by reader.nextline!=null  this condition gets true coz my csv file contains empty line in between previous of tabledata